# How to automatically place the text of a shape on its border?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I would like the text associated with a shape (which is normally centered in the shape) to be **automatically** put, centered, on the upper border:

[image]

I created the picture above by manually placing a text box on the border with a white background and (again manually) centering it on the border. If I move or resize the construction is lost.

I could group these two elements but when resizing (particularly vertically) the text leaves the border. Additionally this does not scale well when I have to create a lot of shapes.

Is there a way to place the label of the shapes as described above by default?

Comment: There's no way to do it other than manually, as you've already done, or via VBA or other code.